# Tailwind CSS: display text on image hover

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How can I show text on image hover, using Tailwind CSS: display text on image hover?

Here is my image? I want text "mammals" to be displayed when user hovers image?

```
<img src="/img/cat/categories/mammals.png" alt="mammals" class="max-w-full max-h-full">
```

Comment: Replace `alt` attribute by `title`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the title atribute in your img tag.

```
<img src="/img/cat/categories/mammals.png" alt="mammals" class="max-w-full max-h-full" title="mammals">
```

Answer (score 23):

I prefer to play around with position relative and absolute because it gives me more options to work with. Check out this code [Display text on hover](https://play.tailwindcss.com/oszCNuYVDu)

```
<div class="w-64 h-64 bg-red-100 relative">
  <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-cover bg-center z-0" style="background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3c/JumanjiTheNextLevelTeaserPoster.jpg')"></div>
  <div class="opacity-0 hover:opacity-100 duration-300 absolute inset-0 z-10 flex justify-center items-center text-6xl text-white font-semibold">Dwayne</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am going to show the title on hover opacity.
Is it possible in Tailwind CSS?

http://prntscr.com/12qt4k5

Comment: @ExpertWeblancer Sure you can. Please create a seperate question for this. That way this is not hidden in some thread's comment. Making it easier for others to follow.

Answer (score 8):

Another idea is using [`group-hover`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#group-hover) class.

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="w-64 bg-red-100 relative group">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3c/JumanjiTheNextLevelTeaserPoster.jpg" />
  <div class="opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 duration-300 absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 flex justify-center items-end text-xl bg-gray-200 text-black font-semibold">Dwayne</div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/jHctOK8vVg)

Answer (score 7):

Please use this code works well

```
  <div class="relative ">
    <a class="absolute inset-0 z-10 bg-white text-center flex flex-col items-center justify-center opacity-0 hover:opacity-100 bg-opacity-90 duration-300">
      <h1  class=tracking-wider >Title</h1>
      <p  class="mx-auto">Description</p>
      </a>
    <a href="#" class="relative">
        <div class="h-48 flex flex-wrap content-center">
            <img src="/image_url" class="mx-auto  " alt="">
        </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I adapted this solution for my case in which I pass dynamically text and img as props in React, as said with some "adaption" works as charm

Comment: I adapted the solution to pass clickable svg icons and text labels for them