# Next JS - <Image />

Tags: next.js

Changing image on mouse hover :

I have a png image , with text engineerign and another picture with same text but different style.

I need on Hover to change between these 2 images.

I did that few times with normal <img TAG but in next js we need to use their <Image tag insted and this is not possible :

```
<Image src={engin} alt={'something'} onMouseOver={e => (e.currentTarget.src = 
engin_fill)} />
```

Help is really appriciated

Comment: Wrap Image in a div having your onMouseOver handler and set src using a state variable.

Comment: I did like this at the end :          const [hover, setHover] = useState(!false);

                                                 const handleHover = () => setHover(!hover);  <Image src={hover ? engin_fill : engin} alt={'engineering'} onMouseOver={handleHover} onMouseLeave={handleHover} />

Answer (score 2):

You can create 2  components inside some wrapper and just switch them on hover

```
<Wrapper onMouseOver={() => setHovered(true)}>
  {!hovered&&<Image1/>}
  {hovered&&<Image2/>}
</Wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Tailwind CSS. After that, the code will look like:

```
<Image src={engin} class="z-20 hover:z-0" />
<div class="z-10">Text</div>
```

e.g.-

```
  <div class="relative ">
<a class="absolute inset-0 z-10 bg-white text-center flex flex-col items-center justify-center opacity-0 hover:opacity-100 bg-opacity-90 duration-300">
  <h1  class=tracking-wider >Title</h1>
  <p  class="mx-auto">Description</p>
  </a>
<a href="#" class="relative">
    <div class="h-48 flex flex-wrap content-center">
        <img src="/image_url" class="mx-auto  " alt="">
    </div>
</a>
```

More answers:
[Tailwind CSS: display text on image hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917029/tailwind-css-display-text-on-image-hover)

How to install tailwind css: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation